# DateValue returns inconsistent types

Tags: date-and-time

More of a 'why' than a 'how' question...

```
DateValue[{2014,4,12},"DayName"]
```

returns Saturday, a symbol rather than the string "Saturday".

Every other result that DateValue returns that is not a number is a string not a symbol so why the special case for Days of the Week?

Just to add to the confusion DayNameShort and DayNameInitial do return strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown inthe documentation, the third parameter of `DateValue` provides control of the form of the value returned. If you want a `String` specify that.

```
DateValue[{2014, 4, 12}, "DayName", String]
```

> "Saturday"

```
Head[%]
```

> String

Comment: Hmm, despite staring at the docs for a long time I seem to have deliberately ignored that one.  Many thanks as that solves a different problem as well.

Comment: +1. Somewhat related. Any reason that the day names are available as Symbols as well as Strings, but the month names only as Strings?

Comment: @RomkeBontekoe - I don't know why Wolfram (company) decided to build in definitions for days as symbols but not months. `DateValue` is then consistent with that decision.